# How to make python on Heroku https only?

Tags: python, django, ssl, https, heroku

I have python/django app on Heroku (Cedar stack) and would like to make it accessible over https only. I have enabled the "ssl piggyback"-option, and can connect to it via https.

But what is the best way to disable http access, or redirect to https?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Combining the answer from @CraigKerstiens and @allanlei into something I have tested, and verified to work. Heroku sets the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO to https when request is ssl, and we can use this to check:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


class SSLMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if not any([settings.DEBUG, request.is_secure(), request.META.get("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO", "") == 'https']):
            url = request.build_absolute_uri(request.get_full_path())
            secure_url = url.replace("http://", "https://")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(secure_url)
```

Comment: Upvote for putting on github...  Thanks!  Just what I was looking for today.

Comment: As a side note, this doesn't work if you have DEBUG set to True. Spent an hour figuring that one out, so hopefully this saves someone some time.

Comment: In this case, remember to add this to settings to let django know requests are secure: SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

Comment: It appears that you cannot serve static files with Django using that middleware. I still don't know why since I'm accessing it through *https*

Comment: request.is_secure() already takes care of the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO header, you should not check for it again, see https://github.com/return1/django-sslify-admin/issues/1 . _Currently, HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO is always inspected. However; this header can be faked. As noted by the devs of django, you should be very explicit with such options: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header._

Comment: I had to manually set SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https') in my settings for is_secure to recognize heroku-style https

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem of cookies being sent in cleartext on the first, non-SSL "GET" request. but then I don't suppose there *is* a fix for that.

Comment: Where do I put this? In what file?

Answer (score 54):

Django 1.8 will have core support for non-HTTPS redirect (integrated from [django-secure](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.8/#security-enhancements)):

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True # [1]
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

In order for `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` to be handled you have to use the `SecurityMiddleware`:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
]
```

[1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#secure-ssl-redirect

Comment: Does this mean the pip package sslify is obsolete as of Django 1.8?

Comment: @dfrankow django-sslify sounds similar to django-secure, but you'll have to confirm that with the package author

Comment: @dfrankow No, you still still need sslify with Django 1.8, if you want to automatically redirect users from http to https.

Comment: sslify's author confirms [here](https://github.com/rdegges/django-sslify/issues/31) that @dfrankow is correct, sslify is obsolete for Django >= 1.8

Comment: Set SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=False for local server and True for production. This can be done by setting environment variable. os.environ.get("SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT")

Comment: Where do I put this? In what file?

Comment: @KovyJacob You probably figured this out by now, but the answer is that all these go in the settings.py ...

Answer (score 13):

Not sure if @CraigKerstiens's answer takes into account that `request.is_secure()` always returns `False` if behind Heroku's reverse proxy and not "fixed". If I remember correctly, this will cause a HTTP redirect loop.

If you are running Django with gunicorn, another way to do it is to add the following to gunicorn's config

```
secure_scheme_headers = {
    'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https'
}
```

Run with some like this in your Procfile

```
web: python manage.py run_gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -c config/gunicorn.conf
```

By setting gunicorn's `secure-scheme-header`, `request.is_secure()` will properly return `True` on https requests. See [Gunicorn Config](http://gunicorn.org/configure.html#secure-scheme-headers).

Now @CraigKerstiens's middleware will work properly, including any calls to `request.is_secure()` in your app.

Note: Django also has the same config setting call `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER`, buts in the dev version.

Comment: The django SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER setting is now available in mainline (certainly in 1.6, maybe earlier).

Comment: Where do I put this? In what file?

Answer (score 6):

What framework are you using for your application? If you're using Django you could simple use some middleware similar to:

```
import re

from django.conf import settings
from django.core import urlresolvers
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect


class SSLMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if not any([settings.DEBUG, request.is_secure()]):
            url = request.build_absolute_uri(request.get_full_path())
            secure_url = url.replace("http://", "https://")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(secure_url)
```

Comment: Yes, I am using django. Thanks for the answer: I will give it a try unless something simpler (like a hidden heroku option) appears..

Comment: I had to make a small tweak to you answer, but the moderators rejected my edit. I have created my own answer which fixes the problem with never-ending redirects in your current answer. Thanks anyway, would never have thought of a middleware-solution without your contribution.

Answer (score 6):

**2020 update:**

If you are using Flask, I would recommend the following:

```py
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if 'DYNO' in os.environ:
        if request.url.startswith('http://'):
            url = request.url.replace('http://', 'https://', 1)
            code = 301
            return redirect(url, code=code)
```

The above works excellent on Heroku and allows you to use `http` in local development with `heroku local`.

Flask-SSLify is no longer maintained and no longer officially supported by the Flask community.

**2014 original answer:**

If you're using Flask, this works quite well:

1. Do "pip install flask-sslify"

(github is here: https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-sslify)

2. Include the following lines:

```py
from flask_sslify import SSLify
if 'DYNO' in os.environ: # only trigger SSLify if the app is running 
on Heroku
    sslify = SSLify(app)
```

Comment: If we do this.... do we still need to do the Heroku stuff? sorry bit new to this stuff

Comment: Though see the issue re "flip-flopping" at https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-sslify/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

For Flask use Talisman. [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/security/#security-headers), [Heroku](https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls) and [SSLify](https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-sslify) documentations favor the use of [Talisman](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman) over SSLify because the later is no longer maintained.

From [SSLify](https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-sslify):

> The extension is no longer maintained, prefer using Flask-Talisman as
> it is encouraged by the Flask Security Guide.

Install via pip:

```
$ pip install flask-talisman
```

Instatiate the extension (example):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_talisman import Talisman

app = Flask(__name__)
if 'DYNO' in os.environ:
    Talisman(app)
```

Talisman enables CSP (Content Security Policy) by default only allowing resources from the same domain to be loaded. If you want to disable it and deal with the implications:

```
Talisman(app, content_security_policy=None)
```

If you don't want to disable it you have to set the `content_security_policy` argument to allow resources from external domains, like CDNs, for instance. For that refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman).