# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS on Flask+Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, https, flask

When I attempt to redirect incoming traffic to https I get an infinite redirect loop.

```
@app.route('/checkout/')                                                                                                                                                                                        
def checkout():                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    checkout = "https://myapp.herokuapp.com/checkout/"                                                                                                                                              
    if checkout != request.url:                                                                                                                                                                             
        print checkout, request.url                                                                                                                                                                             
        return redirect(checkout)                                                                                                                                                                               
    return render_template('checkout.html', key=keys['publishable_key'])
```

The request.url is never changed to prefix https. I want to use heroku's piggyback ssl to minimize cost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Heroku, SSL (https) is terminated before it reaches your application, so you app never actually sees SSL traffic. To check whether a request was made with https, you instead have to inspect the `x-forwarded-proto` header. More info here: [How to make python on Heroku https only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436666/how-to-make-python-on-heroku-https-only)

UPDATE: For your use, you should just check request.url for "myapp.herokuapp.com/checkout/"; and verify that the header is "https"

Comment: Thanks friism. I have seen the flask-sslify package. Which would meet my needs except I'm using a custom domain along with heroku's subdomain. I only want to put SSL on one page. Thanks for the doc though, I will read through it.

Comment: You should just check `request.url` for "http://myapp.herokuapp.com/checkout/" and verify that the header is "https"

Comment: Thanks, that's what did it.

Comment: I've added the comment in the answer - please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: I will heavily consider :) If you mention flask-sslify in your answer I will consider even more heavily.

Answer (score 15):

1) Do "pip install flask-sslify"

(github is here: https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-sslify)

2) Include the following lines:

```
from flask_sslify import SSLify
if 'DYNO' in os.environ: # only trigger SSLify if the app is running on Heroku
    sslify = SSLify(app)
```

Comment: The `'DYNO' in os.environ` tip is particularly useful.

Answer (score 6):

I tried SSLify, url_for _scheme, and setting a PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME; however none worked out, at the release level at least.. (worked fine locally) Then I thought;

```
@app.before_request
def beforeRequest():
    if not request.url.startswith('https'):
        return redirect(request.url.replace('http', 'https', 1))
```

This is essentially another way to get it done without any configurations, or extensions.

Comment: This resulted in "This webpage has a redirect loop" for me

Comment: @tdc Interesting, did you try the answer I gave before someone edited this answer? I haven't tried this, although it seems it should work the same; I know the original definitely worked fine.

Comment: I never saw the original! SSLify worked for me in the end

Answer (score 0):

I was able to repurpose the flask-sslify code for a single view. Just needed to check whether or not the request was being made with SSL and add proper headers to the response. https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-sslify

```
@app.route('/checkout/')                                                                                                                                                                                        
def checkout():                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    checkout = "https://myapp.herokuapp.com/checkout/"                                                                                                                                              
    if request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-Proto', 'http') == 'https':                                                                                                                                             
        resp = make_response(render_template('checkout.html', key=keys['publishable_key']))                                                                                                              
        return set_hsts_header(resp)                                                                                                                                                                            
    return redirect(checkout, code=302)                                                                                                                                                                         

def set_hsts_header(response):                                                                                                                                                                                  
    """Adds HSTS header to each response."""                                                                                                                                                                    
    response.headers.setdefault('Strict-Transport-Security', hsts_header)                                                                                                                                       
    return response                                                                                                                                                                                             

def hsts_header():                                                                                                                                                                                              
    """Returns the proper HSTS policy."""                                                                                                                                                                       
    hsts_policy = 'max-age={0}'.format(31536000) #year in seconds                                                                                                                                               
    if self.hsts_include_subdomains:                                                                                                                                                                            
        hsts_policy += '; includeSubDomains'                                                                                                                                                                    
        return hsts_policy
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header. If its false, redirect to the equivalent https url.

Here the code to enforce https for all calls on a flask app running on heroku:

```
@app.before_request
def enforceHttpsInHeroku():
  if request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-Proto') == 'http':
  url = request.url.replace('http://', 'https://', 1)
  code = 301
  return redirect(url, code=code)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if 'DYNO' in os.environ: # Only runs when on heroku
        if request.url.startswith('http://'):
            url = request.url.replace('http://', 'https://', 1)
            code = 301
            return redirect(url, code=code)
```

Answer (score 0):

On my answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67611776/15016163) I have stated the upto date Flask recommendations. Use Talisman instead of SSLify.

> For Flask use [Talisman](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman). [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/security/#security-headers), [Heroku](https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls) and [SSLify](https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-sslify)
> documentations favor the use of [Talisman](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman) over SSLify because the
> later is no longer maintained.
>
> From [SSLify](https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-sslify):
>
> > The extension is no longer maintained, prefer using Flask-Talisman as
> > it is encouraged by the Flask Security Guide.
>
> Install via pip:
>
> ```
> $ pip install flask-talisman
> ```
>
> Instatiate the extension (example):
>
> ```
> from flask import Flask
> from flask_talisman import Talisman
>
> app = Flask(__name__)
> if 'DYNO' in os.environ:
>     Talisman(app)
> ```
>
> Talisman enables CSP (Content Security Policy) by default only
> allowing resources from the same domain to be loaded. If you want to
> disable it and deal with the implications:
>
> ```
> Talisman(app, content_security_policy=None)
> ```
>
> If you don't want to disable it you have set the
> `content_security_policy` argument to allow resources from external
> domains, like CDNs, for instance. For that refer to the
> [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman).