# Force Django to use HTTPS URLs when reversing

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, cloud9-ide, django-1.6

I am running my Django application in Cloud9 for development purposes using the usual ./manage.py runserver. But to the outside world, the app is accessible via a https:// URL.

The problem is that when I use the URL reverse function, the URLs that come back start with http:// (at least some of the time). When I try redirecting to one of those URLs, I get an error like this one in the console:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://apps.facebook.com/xxxx/' 
was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure form action 
'http://xxxx.c9users.io/facebook_app/gift_shop/'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

My question: is there a way to force reverse to generate HTTPS URLs instead of HTTP?

Here is a snippet of code, which has problems with redirection from HTTPS URLs to HTTP ones:

```
class IndexRedirectView(RedirectView, CSRFExemptMixin):
    permanent = False

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.visit_count >= 5:
            return reverse('gift-shop')
        if len(BaseGiftableInstance.objects.filter(giving_user=self.request.user)) > 0:
            # has won something
            return reverse('gift-shop')
        return reverse('spinner')
```

Comment: **YOU MUST NOT RUN YOUR PRODUCTION SITE WITH RUNSERVER**.

Comment: @DanielRoseman This is not my production site.

Comment: It's publicly accessible though. Don't do this. Configure a proper webserver.

Comment: I still need debugging features to ease the development. And I am using Cloud9, so Facebook can have access to the application.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Cloud9 is a cloud based IDE. Chill out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should check out [django-sslify](https://github.com/rdegges/django-sslify/), you just install it and add it to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

Answer (score 10):

If you are on Django 1.8 or greater, you can force SSL with the setting `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26670053/354176) on a similar question